# Difference or similarity between a biology and genetic algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithms

> What id the difference/similarity between a biological chromosome and
>   a chromosome from a genetic algorithm?

A biological chromosome represents a specific living organism who can be a result of an evolution, and can be a starting point of a new evolution.

A chromosome in the genetic algorithm represents a specific solution. This solution can act as the starting input of the genetic algorithm and can participate in creating new solutions, or can be a result of an algorithmic evolution.

> What id the difference/similarity between a biological population and
>   a population from a genetic algorithm?

In biology, population means a collection of living organisms. Since, one chromosome represents one living organism, we can also say that a population is a collection of chromosomes.

In genetic algorithm, population means a collection of chromosomes.

I.e. a set of chromosomes == a collection of possible solutions.

**Am I correct?**